# Change get_posts to loop.php suitable version

Tags: php, wordpress

I didn't know that get_posts doesn't work with `loop.php`. I already have this great `loop.php` file and I want to use it.
I created this code:

```
$pageposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'post__in' => $postid,
        'post_type'   => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'st_date', 
                'value'  => array($todate_s, $frmdate_s),
                'compare'=> 'BETWEEN',
                'type'   => 'DATE'
              ),
        ),
    )
);
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
<?php else : ?>//etc
```

How I can convert the `get_posts(//etc)` to something that work with `have_posts()` and `get_template_part('loop')` at the end of my code?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You get confused between `query_posts();` and `get_posts();` try this:

```
<?php
$pageposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'post__in' => $postid,
        'post_type'   => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'st_date', 
                'value'  => array($todate_s, $frmdate_s),
                'compare'=> 'BETWEEN',
                'type'   => 'DATE'
              ),
        ),
    )
);

foreach ( $pageposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

    get_template_part('loop');

endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
<?php
query_posts(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'post__in' => $postid,
        'post_type'   => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'st_date', 
                'value'  => array($todate_s, $frmdate_s),
                'compare'=> 'BETWEEN',
                'type'   => 'DATE'
              ),
        ),
    )
);

get_template_part('loop');

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: This is a great idea, but will not work. I used `if (have_posts())` inside the `loop.php`

Comment: There are many options i.e. 1. convert the above code to query_posts 2. keep it but write the correct loop inside 3. save the loop to loop-event, and call it.

Comment: Updated the answer for it.